# html button is rendering below the input box

Tags: html, css

I have a input box for users to enter search terms in.  I have a input button beside the search box.  for some reason the button is rendering below the search box.

**I want the button to be right beside the input box.**

My html:

```
 <div id="searchbox">
                <form method="post" action="/search/test">
                <div class="searchinput">
                    <input type="text" id="searchbox" value="" /></div>
                <div class="searchbutton">
                    <input type="submit" id="searchboxbutton" value="Go" /></div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
#header #searchbox 
{
    float:left;
    width:400px;
    padding:5px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#header #searchbox #searchinput
{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
#header #searchbox #searchbox
{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
#header #searchbox #searchbutton 
{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplify, simplify, simplify.

HTML

```
    <form method="post" action="/search/test">
        <input type="text" id="searchbox" value="" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchboxbutton" value="Go" />
    </form>
```

CSS

```
input {display: inline}
```

Comment: This is the true solution. My answer was the direct solution to the problem. This code is what it ultimately ought to be. +1

Comment: Thanks Neatly.

Also, Blankman, your text input should really have an accompanying label tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<input type="text" id="searchbox" value="" />` is matching this style (width: 400px) as well:

```
#header #searchbox 
{
    float:left;
    width:400px;
    padding:5px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

IDs must be unique - change it or the containing element and write your styles accordingly.

http://validator.w3.org/docs/errors.html

> 141: ID X already defined
>
> ```
> An "id" is a unique identifier. Each time this attribute is used in a
> ```
>
> document it must have a different
>   value. If you are using this attribute
>   as a hook for style sheets it may be
>   more appropriate to use classes (which
>   group elements) than id (which are
>   used to identify exactly one element).

Answer (score 1):

Just add this CSS to your CSS style sheet:

```css
.searchinput{
 display:inline-block
}
```

It will add your content in one row.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your #searchbox width is 400px and your input tag and button tag is more than 400 px.

Try making the #searchbox width to 600px and see what happens.

Change your css from

```
#header #searchbox 
{
    float:left;
    width:400px;
    padding:5px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#header #searchbox #searchinput
{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
#header #searchbox #searchbox
{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
#header #searchbox #searchbutton 
{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
```

}

to

```
#header
{
    float:left;
    width:400px;
    padding:5px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#searchinput, #searchbox, #searchbutton, #searchboxbutton
{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an id based selector in CSS (`#searchinput`) but you are using classes in markup (`<div class="searchinput">`). Change either of the ones and it should work.

Third, you don't need the `display:inline`. Just `float: left` will do. Also, floated elements are required to have a width. So set a width.

Comment: If he did that he wouldn't need to have 4 lines of almost the same thing. He does however need to fix the order of it. He has #header #searchbox #searchinput but it should be #header #searchinput #searchbox. You have to traverse the children correctly.

Comment: ugh, I missed that. I edited my answer. It is however pointless and extremely inefficient to specify a hierarchy to id based selectors. You are allowed to have only one element with an id.